# Combine multiple mono in Spring Webflux

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I'm new with webflux and I'm trying to execute multiple monos with `Flux`. But i think i'm doing it wrong.. is this the best approach to execute multiple `Mono` and collect it to list?

Here is my code:

```java
    mainService.getAllBranch()
            .flatMapMany(branchesList -> {
                List<Branch> branchesList2 = (List<Branch>) branchesList.getData();
                List<Mono<Transaction>> trxMonoList= new ArrayList<>();

                branchesList2.stream().forEach(branch -> {
                    trxMonoList.add(mainService.getAllTrxByBranchId(branch.branchId));
                });
                return Flux.concat(trxMonoList); // <--- is there any other way than using concat?
            })
            .collectList()
            .flatMap(resultList -> combineAllList());
```

```java
    interface MainService{
            Mono<RespBody> getAllBranch();
            Mono<RespBody> getAllTrxByBranchId(String branchId); //will return executed url ex: http://trx.com/{branchId}
    }
```

so far my with above code i can explain it like this:

1. Get all branches
2. iterate through all `branchesList2` and add it to `trxMonoList`
3. return `Flux.concat`, this is where i'm not sure is this the right way or not. but it's working
4. combine all list

I'm just confuse is this the proper way to use `Flux` in my context? or is there any better way to achieve with what i'm trying to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to refactor a little bit your code to reactive.

```
 mainService.getAllBranch()
        .flatMapMany(branchesList -> Flux.fromIterable(branchesList.getData())) (1)
        .flatMap(branch -> mainService.getAllTrxByBranchId(branch.branchId))    (2)
        .collectList()
        .flatMap(resultList -> combineAllList());
```

1) Create *Flux* of branches from List;

2) Iterate through the each element and call a service.

You shouldn't use Stream API in Reactor because it has the same methods but with adaptaptions and optimisations for multythreading.

Comment: the **(2)** that you pointed, doesn't seem work as you said. it doesn't **iterate through the each element and call a service**. it's only executed one time.

Comment: Could you please add log() operator to the operator’s chain?

Comment: i just checked it again, it turns out that when i'm adding `mainService.getAllTrxByBranchId(branch.branchId)` **.zipWith(cookie)** i only get 1 list. so how can i pass my cookie along with branchList? i've tried `concateWith` but i don't have any idea how to do it.

Comment: okay it's solved now. from [flux documentation](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/)  about `zipWith`  **"that is to say wait for both to emit one element and combine these elements once into a Tuple2."** That's why I'm only receiving the 1st element of the list.

Answer (score 1):

The real problem here is that you shouldn't be hitting a `Mono` multiple times within a `Flux`. That will give you problems. If you are designing the API you should fix that to do what you want in a correct reactive manner.

```
interface MainService{
        Flux<Branch> getAllBranch();
        Flux<Transaction> getAllTrxByBranchId(Flux<String> branchIds);
}
```

Then your code becomes simpler and the reactive framework will work properly.

```
mainService.getAllTrxByBranchId(mainService.getAllBranch().map(Branch::getId));
```